# Django NoReverseMatch Error on Update and Delete Buttons

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-tables2

Thank you for reading my question, and for your help.

I wrote a simple CRUD app, and used django-tables2 module to make my tables look pretty and more robust. I am using django 3.2, python 3.8.5, django_tables2 2.3.4.

I can enter a query in the search bar on the home.html page and lists the returned results from a postgresql on the search_results.html page. On the search_results page, I have buttons next to each returned row with edit and delete options, when I hover over update buttons it points to url for localhost:8955/update/7887 or localhost:8955/delete/7887 for the delete button, of course the last four digits are unique to the returned rows, however when I click on the update or delete button I get a NoReverseMatch error. I am at my wits end what is  causing the edit and delete buttons not to work, your help and assistance is very much appreciated it.

[Image with the returned results with the update and delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYtjL.jpg)

tables.py

```
from .models import EsgDatabase
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as user

class EsgListViewTable(tables.Table):


    class Meta:
        model = EsgDatabase
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html"
        fields = ('id','role', 'hq','system','market','state','zone','arrisseachangezone','xgsystem','xgzonecode','fto','xocnoc','snowticketassignment',)
        
    if user.is_authenticated:
        edit = TemplateColumn(template_name='update.html')
        delete = TemplateColumn(template_name='delete.html')
```

app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import HomePageView, SearchResultsView, EsgCreateView, EsgUpdateView, EsgDeleteView, EsgDetailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(),name='search_results',),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('createform/', EsgCreateView.as_view(), name='createform'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', EsgUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', EsgDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete' ),
    path('details/<int:pk>', EsgDetailView.as_view(), name='details'),
   
]
```

views.py

```
from .models import EsgDatabase
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, DetailView
from django_tables2 import SingleTableView
from esgsheet.tables import EsgListViewTable

class EsgDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'details.html'
    model = EsgDatabase
    table_class = EsgListViewTable
    context_object_name = 'esgdetail'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('details',kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'esghome'

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class EsgDeleteView(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'delete.html'
    model = EsgDatabase
    table_class = EsgListViewTable
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    context_object_name = 'deleteview'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('home',kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class EsgUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = EsgDatabase
    fields = '__all__'
    table_class = EsgListViewTable
    template_name = 'update.html'
    context_object_name = 'esgupdate'


    strong textdef get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('details', kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class EsgCreateView(CreateView):
    model = EsgDatabase
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'forms.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('details', kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})


class SearchResultsView(SingleTableView): 
    model = EsgDatabase
    table_class = EsgListViewTable
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    SingleTableView.table_pagination = False 
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            object_list = EsgDatabase.objects.filter(
                Q(role__icontains=query) | Q(hq__icontains=query) |
                Q(system__icontains=query) | Q(market__icontains=query) |Q(state__icontains=query) |
                Q(zone__icontains=query) |Q(arrisseachangezone__icontains=query) |Q(xgsystem__icontains=query) |
                Q(xgzonecode__icontains=query) | Q(syscode__icontains=query) |Q(fto__icontains=query) |
                Q(xocnoc__icontains=query) |Q(snowticketassignment__icontains=query)
                )
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.none()
        return object_list
```

base.html

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <center> 
  {% block title %}
 {% endblock title %}
</center>
  </head>
  
  <body>
   <!-- {% url 'home' as home %}
     {% if request.path != home %}
     
    <center> <br>
      <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="GET">
      <input name='q' type="text" placeholder="Search ESG Database">
      </form> <br>
    </center>

    {% endif %} -->

 


   {% block content %}
   {% endblock content %}
  </body>

</html>
```

home.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% block title  %}
 <h1>ESG Database</h1>
 {% endblock title  %}
 
 {% block content %}




       <center> 
           <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="GET">
            <input name='q' type="text" placeholder="Search ESG Database">
            </form> 
        </center>


        
{% endblock content %}
```

delete.html

```
{% block title  %}
{% endblock title  %}
{% block content %}

<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  
</form>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<a type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{% url 'delete' record.id %}" >Delete.html</a>




{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

update.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title  %}
{% endblock title  %}
{% block content %}
        <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form.as_p}}
   
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    
          <a type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url 'update' record.id %}" >Update.html</a>
          {% endif %}
        </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

search_results.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block title %}
<h1>ESG Database Results</h1>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{% render_table table %}


{% endblock content %}
```

forms.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title  %}
<h1>Create ESG Entry</h1>
{% endblock title  %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   {% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

details.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title  %}
<h1>Updated Detail View</h1>
{% endblock title  %}

{% block content %}

 <table class="table table-hover"> 
    <thead>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>HQ</th>
        <th>System</th>
        <th>Market</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zone</th>
        <th>Arris/SeaChange Zone</th>
        <th>xG System</th>
        <th>xG Zone Code</th>
        <th>Syscode</th>
        <th>FTO</th>
        <th>XOC/NOC</th>
        <th>SNOW Ticket Assignment</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>


  
      
    <tr>

    <td>{{esgdetail.role}}</td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.hq}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.system}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.market}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.state}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.zone}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.arrisseachangezone}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.xgsystem}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.xgzonecode}} </td>
    <td> {{esgdetail.syscode}} </td>
    <td> {{esgdetail.fto}} </td>
    <td>{{esgdetail.xocnoc}} </td>
    <td> {{esgdetail.snowticketassignment}} </td>
    <!-- <td>
        <a href="{% url 'update' esgdetail.id %}">edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'delete' esgdetail.id %}">delete</a>
       
       
    </td> -->
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table> 



{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I can create new entries in the database and read/retrieve entries, but I cannot update or delete entries. Here is part of the error message when I click on delete button 
```
NoReverseMatch at /delete/7887
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.0.0.67:8955/delete/7887
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

```

Comment: Try adding application name and `:` into url tag, for example: `"{% url 'search_results' %}"` --> `"{% url '<your_app_name_here>:search_results' %}"`

Comment: @Lewis Thank you for the suggestion. In home.html I updated to ``` <center> 
           <form action="{% url 'esgsheet:search_results' %}" method="GET">
            <input name='q' type="text" placeholder="Search ESG Database">
            </form> 
        </center>```  

New error I get is, 
```
NoReverseMatch at /
'esgsheet' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.0.0.67:8955/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
'esgsheet' is not a registered namespace
```

Comment: I see you have your app `urls.py` but can you show your root `urls.py` please. Will be in your project folder

Comment: Here is the root's urls.py 
```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('esgsheet.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

```

Comment: Also added app_name='esgsheet' in app's urls.py as a result home page not load
***************************************************
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('esgsheet.urls', namespace='esgsheet')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @funkybob at #django irc room. First I had to delete comments from my code because it was being parsed throwing NoReverseMatch errors. Second, I had to remove context_object_name from update and delete views.